# django - next higest number in a list

Tags: python, django, list

My users can save their settings for access to their pages as a comma seperated integer list. Users will have a different list value depending on the settings they save. For example:

User 1: 0,1,22,2,3,4,5,26,6,7,23,8,9,25,11,12,10,13,14,27,15,24,16,17,18,19,20,21

User 2: 6,22,8

User 3: 0,1,2,26,6,7,23,8,25,11,12,10

...

In my views.py I am trying to write an if statement that when given a number, I can assign a "next highest number" that occurs in the list. For example, in the code below, the variable "settings.MENU_DETAIL_VALUE_ACH_DETAILS" is equal to 8.

How do I write the code to get the next highest number (after 8) that occurs in the list. For user 1, 2 & 3, the next highest number would be 9, 22 and 10, respectively.

Here is my attempt at the code. The if condition, checks that 8 is in the list. The 2nd line of code should then assign the next highest number to the variable "next_highest_num_in_list":

```
if str(settings.MENU_DETAIL_VALUE_ACH_DETAILS) in selected_menu_list:

    next_highest_num_in_list = ??UNABLE TO WRITE THIS CODE HERE??
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
>>> u1 = [0,1,22,2,3,4,5,26,6,7,23,8,9,25,11,12,10,13,14,27,15,24,16,17,18,19,20,21]
>>> u2 = 6,22,8
>>> u3 = 0,1,2,26,6,7,23,8,25,11,12,10


>>> def get_next_highest(num, *lists):
    lists = list(map(sorted, lists))
    for l in lists:
        print(l[l.index(num)+1])


>>> get_next_highest(8, u1, u2, u3)
9
22
10
```

Next, it's your job to improve the function to work with that specific case :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am still new to django and I have been trying to get this code adapted to work for me.

I dont fully understand the for loop - what does the "*lists" mean and how is it different to "lists"?

Comment: It's used so you can input multiple lists at once. Just try to pass `*selected_menu_list`.

Comment: The following code is returning an error stating 8 is not in the list:

def get_selected_resume_menu_entries(user):
    
    list01 = list(map(sorted, user.get_profile().selected_resume_menu_entries))
    for l in list01:
        next_resume_page = (l[l.index((settings.MENU_DETAIL_VALUE_ACHIEVEMENT_DETAILS))+1])
        
    return next_resume_page


Any suggestions?

Comment: Try printing the lists, make sure it's the one you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

For such short lists, you may as well just use list_.sort() and list_.index() or list_.find().

If your lists were longer and you were accessing this kind of information a lot, I might recommend something like: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/red-black-tree-mod , because it has a foo.successor() operator and is faster than sorting inside a loop.

Full disclosure: I maintain that red-black tree implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of 'Readability Counts' here is my getNextSettingPage function. Also I went ahead and added a user case that does not contain the magic number you are looking for, to round out the example. i.e. `u4 = [ 2,6,12,22 ]`

```
def getNextSettingPage(user_settings, previous_page):
   user_settings.sort()
   try:
      new_index = user_settings.index( previous_page )
      return user_settings[new_index + 1]
   except ValueError:
      # not sure what you want to do here
      return previous_page

if __name__ == '__main__':
   u1 = [0,1,22,2,3,4,5,26,6,7,23,8,9,25,11,12,10,13,14,27,15,24,16,17,18,19,20,21]
   u2 = [6,22,8]
   u3 = [0,1,2,26,6,7,23,8,25,11,12,10]
   u4 = [2,6,12,22]

   MENU_DETAIL_VALUE_ACH_DETAILS=8

   next_page = getNextSettingPage(u1, MENU_DETAIL_VALUE_ACH_DETAILS)
   print "Next Page for User 1: %d" % ( next_page )

   next_page = getNextSettingPage(u2, MENU_DETAIL_VALUE_ACH_DETAILS)
   print "Next Page for User 2: %d" % ( next_page )

   next_page = getNextSettingPage(u3, MENU_DETAIL_VALUE_ACH_DETAILS)
   print "Next Page for User 3: %d" % ( next_page )

   next_page = getNextSettingPage(u4, MENU_DETAIL_VALUE_ACH_DETAILS)
   print "Next Page for User 4: %d" % ( next_page )
```

Outputs:

```
Next Page for User 1: 9
Next Page for User 2: 22
Next Page for User 3: 10
Next Page for User 4: 8
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for your code. I almost have my version working. 

One last questions is how would I find the next highest number if the list is as follows: 

[u'0', u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5', u'6', u'7', u'8', u'9', u'10', u'11', u'12', u'13', u'14', u'15', u'16', u'17', u'18', u'19', u'20', u'21', u'22', u'23', u'24', u'25', u'26', u'27']